# mail function return false and does not mail in php

Tags: php, email

I am working in html and php.I want to send mail for hotel booking.And I am working in server not in localhost.

My html file is like this.

index.html

```
<form id="reservation-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php"> 
<div class="clearfix anim-7-all wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-offset="5">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="message" class="date-picker" value="" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Time">
    </div>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"><input type="submit" class="theme-btn pull-right" name="s" value="Send" /></div>

</form>
```

This is my php file.

sendemail.php

Here I got all posted value.But i could not send mail.

```
// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Doe" ); 
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "example@gmail.com" );



$senderName = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['name'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$subject = isset( $_POST['subject'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['subject'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $message ) {
$recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
$suc= mail($recipient,$subject,$message,$headers );
//var_dump($suc);
```

}

When I return mail it retun false. So what code should i have to write to solve this?

Comment: Check your mail logs and/or talk to the server admin.

Comment: Have you tried to do a print of the values your passing in the mail $recipient and $headers ? What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `error_get_last()` when `mail()` returns false.

Place the below code after `$suc = mail()` line.

```
if($suc){//If success
   print_r("No error");        
}
else{//If error on mail send
   print_r(error_get_last());
}
exit();//Remove this after debuging done
```

Please let me know if you face any error regarding this.